# Wix 3.0: When upgrading an installation, some components are removed instead of updated

Tags: wix

I dont know if I'm the only one experiencing this. But sometimes in my installer, when I choose  upgrade an installation, it instead removes the files for a certain feature. Now the hard part is, this is intermittent. Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a [component rule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372830%28VS.85%29.aspx) violation but it's really hard to diagnosis without looking at the  1st and 2nd installer and/or installation logs.   Read [How to enable Windows Installer logging](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300) and then look through the log for clues on why MSI is doing what it's doing.  If you can post your log publically others can help you also.